# Row_DataBound or Row_Created event in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have doubt about the `Row_DataBound` and `Row_Created` events :

1. What is the difference between `Row_DataBound` and `Row_Created` events?
2. What are the parameters for choosing between these two events?

Comment: Which object are you referring to? DataRow?

Comment: @Charlie:I am talking about DataBound control like GridView,DataList and Repeater

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RowCreated occurs after a row and all of its child controls are created.

RowDataBound occurs after the row (and its controls) are databound, i.e. populated with the data values.

The answer about which to use really depends on if you need the databound values or not. e.g. If you wanted to change the background color of your row based the value of one of your fields, then you would have to use the RowDataBound event. If your logic doesn't depend on the data, then I don't think it matters which event you use.

An example of where you would have to use RowCreated is if you had a drop down list in your row that would need to be popluated with values before the selected value was databound.

Comment: @Jim:I have seen several times that people used these two events interchangeably  for the same task

Comment: Depending on your needs, they could be used interchangeably.  For example, if you just wanted to change the style of a control or some other attribute that did not depend on the data values, you could use either event.

Comment: @Jim Harte:If I am wrong correct me.You want to say that for cosmetic changes like style sheet or javascript,we can used either of these two events

Comment: @geek: Moved my last comment to my answer.  Please mark it as accepted unless you still have questions.